# How to change description of Refind entries?

Tags: refind

A minor problem (not really a problem at all), and more of just a curious question. Is there any way to change the description of boot options in Refind? I'm using it to triple boot my Mac, and the OS X and Windows entries have nice descriptions; they just say "Boot OS X from Macintosh HD," or something like that, whereas my Ubuntu option says "Boot EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi from EFI," which doesn't look as nice. I understand the value of knowing exactly what you're booting (it's helped me solve problems in the past), but is there any way, just for the sake of looks in the menu itself, I could change that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. Your description is a little thin on information. I don't think I can give a complete answer based on what I have read. Basically, you add a manual entry in `refind.conf` and add line to remove the option with the ugly label. I assume you are looking for something like this. (Click on image for a better view.)

[image]

To produce the above menu, I added the following lines to the default refind.conf file. Again, I do not know enough about your computer to list the changes you will have to make.

```
scanfor manual,internal,hdbios,external,biosexternal,optical,cd
dont_scan_dirs +,/System/Library/CoreServices
menuentry "Mac OS X" {
    icon \System\Library\CoreServices\icons\os_mac.png
    volume "Steelhead"
    loader \System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi
    graphics on
}
dont_scan_dirs +,EFI/ubuntu,Bullhead:/boot
menuentry "Linux Ubuntu" {
    icon \System\Library\CoreServices\icons\os_ubuntu.png
    volume "Bullhead ESP"
    loader \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
    graphics on
}
showtools shell,memtest,gdisk,apple_recovery,windows_recovery,about,shutdown,reboot,firmware
```

Also, when holding down the Option key at boot, you can have the Ubuntu option appear as follows.

[image]

On the OS X Startup Disk menu, you can have Ubuntu appear as follows.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great response. I thought it would have something to do with the custom entry; I just wasn't entirely sure how to go about making one. But to be clear, you have it not-scan the directory you want to boot, then make a custom menu entry? I'll see if I can figure it out, but in the meantime, what more information, and from where, could I provide that would make it easier to help in the creation of the menuentry, or in general? Super long comment, sorry. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Note that if you boot Linux kernels directly, rather than boot via GRUB, this approach means more maintenance, since you'll have to update those entries whenever you add new kernels. For booting via GRUB (or ELILO or SYSLINUX), though, this should work fine. It would also work OK if your distribution creates a link to the latest kernel, in which case you could build a custom entry that points to the link rather than the actual kernel file.